# JavaScript regex escape multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Is is possible escape parameterized regex when parameter contains multiple simbols that need to be escaped?

```
const _and = '&&', _or = '||';
let reString = `^(${_and}|${_or})`; //&{_or} needs to be escaped
const reToken = new RegExp(reString);
```

Working but not optimal:

```
_or = '\\|\\|';
```

Or:

```
let reString = `^(${_and}|\\|\\|)`;
```

It is preferred to reuse `_or` variable and keep regex parameterized.

Comment: Btw. you can use `and` and `or` names for variables, as these in javascript aren't [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). No need to add `_` prefix, which some people add to private properties names. Not saying that you should, but you definitely can. :)

Comment: Yup. Thank you. I guess it's mental consequence of having python backend :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own function which would escape your parameters, so that these works in final regexp. To save you time, I already found one written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/4530649). With that function, you can write clean parameters without actually escaping everything by hand. Though I would avoid modifying build in classes (RegExp) and make a wrapper around it or something separate. In example below I use exact function I found in the other answer, which extends build in RegExp.

```
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

const and = RegExp.escape('&&');
const or = RegExp.escape('||');

const andTestString = '1 && 2';
const orTestString = '1 || 2';
const regexp = `${and}|${or}`;

console.log(new RegExp(regexp).test(andTestString)); // true
console.log(new RegExp(regexp).test(orTestString)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**
https://jsfiddle.net/ao4t0pzr/1/

You can use a Template Literal function to escape the characters within the string using a Regular Expression. You can then use that string to propagate a new RegEx filled with escaped characters:

```js
    function escape(s) {
        return s[0].replace(/[-&\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    };
    
    var or = escape`||`;
    var and = escape`&&`;
    console.log(new RegExp(`${and}|${or}`)); // "/\&\&|\|\|/"
```